# Can you play multiplayer in Minecraft without Xbox Live?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Can you play multiplayer in Minecraft without Xbox Live?

Answer (score 1):

You can play local splitscreen only without Xbox Live.  Per the Minecraft Wiki:

> On Xbox, Local Splitscreen can be played using Local, Silver and Gold accounts, while Online Splitscreen can only be played using Gold and Guest accounts. Guest accounts can only be signed in at the start of a session; they can not join existing sessions. They can only be an Xbox Live account.

A [Silver Account](https://www.lifewire.com/what-is-xbox-live-silver-3563184) is one that takes advantage of the free Xbox Live services only.  The biggest difference with this kind of account is that you cannot participate in online multiplayer.  A local account (as its refereed to in the quote) is one with neither Gold or Silver membership.

The only time you cannot play a game without internet connectivity (using the Xbox offline), is when it's not your [Home Xbox console](https://support.xbox.com/xbox-one/games/my-home-xbox) and the game you are trying to play is a digitally owned one (downloaded via the Store).  Disc games will always work, but digital ones will only work offline on your home console.